# Random sentence creation using Word 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, random, word-2007

How to create a random sentence in word using VBA?

For example the code beneath created a sentence the cat sat on the mat1.
I would like to declare words in place of i.

Is it possible using VBA?

```
    Sub Randomsentence()
    Dim text As String
    Dim s As String
    MyText = "The cat sat on the"
    i = Int(4 * Rnd())
    Selection.TypeText (MyText)
    Selection.TypeText (i)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Type *=lorem()* and press enter to generate a lorem ipsum.

Comment: I want to declare words in random variable and call it on program run. For example the result should be. The cat sat on the mat. The cat sat on the floor. etc. where the words mat floor are hardcoded and called upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following declafres an array and fills it with words. Then a random word is selected from the array and added to the sentence (shown as MsgBox for simplicity):

```
Sub Randomsentence()
    Dim MyText As String
    Dim s(5) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    s(1) = "mat"
    s(2) = "floor"
    s(3) = "roof"
    s(4) = "car"
    s(5) = "garage"
    MyText = "The cat sat on the "
    i = Int(5 * Rnd())
    MsgBox MyText & s(i)
End Sub
```

A maybe nicer way to do that is to read the words from a file. I leave that to you as a nice excercise.